# Problem with reading csv file Python Flask Application

Tags: python, pandas, csv, flask

I created a Python Flask App. It reads **salary.csv** file and outputs some data from that file. Right now, my app works perfectly fine as long as the salary.csv file is inside the same folder where app.py is located. But If I don't have salary.csv in the same folder and try to upload it, it gives me this error
FileNotFoundError

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] File salary.csv does not exist: 'salary.csv'**

app.py

```
import pandas
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')


def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/', methods=['POST'])

def index_post():
    if request.method == 'POST':
#Storing salaries.csv data into a pandas dataframe
        req = request.form['fileToUpload']
        df = pandas.read_csv(req)
#Just calculating some data from dataframe 
        base_pay_MEAN = "{:.2f}".format(df['BasePay'].mean())
        base_pay_MAX = "{:.2f}".format(df['BasePay'].max())
        base_pay_MIN = "{:.2f}".format(df['BasePay'].min())

        overtime_MAX = df['OvertimePay'].max()
        highest_paid_Person_NAME = (df[df['TotalPayBenefits'] == max(df['TotalPayBenefits'])]).iloc[0]['EmployeeName']
        highest_paid_Person_SALARY = (df[df['TotalPayBenefits'] == max(df['TotalPayBenefits'])]).iloc[0]['TotalPayBenefits']
        highest_paid_Person_JOB = (df[df['TotalPayBenefits'] == max(df['TotalPayBenefits'])]).iloc[0]['JobTitle']

        lowest_paid_Person_NAME = (df[df['TotalPayBenefits'] == min(df['TotalPayBenefits'])]).iloc[0]['EmployeeName']
        lowest_paid_Person_SALARY = (df[df['TotalPayBenefits'] == min(df['TotalPayBenefits'])]).iloc[0]['TotalPayBenefits']
        lowest_paid_Person_JOB = (df[df['TotalPayBenefits'] == min(df['TotalPayBenefits'])]).iloc[0]['JobTitle']
        num_Unique_Jobs = df['JobTitle'].nunique()
        most_common_jobs = df.groupby('JobTitle').count().sort_values(by='Id', ascending=False)['Id'].head(3)        

#Returning the data to webpage
        return render_template('index.html',
        base_pay_Title="Basepay",
        base_pay_MEAN=( "Mean: $" + str(base_pay_MEAN)),
        base_pay_MAX=( "Max: $" + str(base_pay_MAX)),
        base_pay_MIN=( "Min: $" + str(base_pay_MIN)),
        over_time_Title="Overtime",
        over_time_MAX=("Max: $" + str(overtime_MAX)),
        highest_paid_Title = "Highest Paid",
        highest_paid_person=("Name: " + str(highest_paid_Person_NAME)),
        highest_paid_job=("Job: " + str(highest_paid_Person_JOB)),
        highest_paid_salary=("Salary: $" + str(highest_paid_Person_SALARY)),
        lowest_pay_Title = "Lowest Paid",
        lowest_paid_person=("Name: " + str(lowest_paid_Person_NAME)),
        lowest_paid_job=("Job: " + str(lowest_paid_Person_JOB)),
        lowest_paid_salary=("Salary: $" + str(lowest_paid_Person_SALARY))
        )
    else:
        render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
   app.run(host="localhost", port=7000, debug=True)
```

index.html

````
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/main.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <h1>
                Some Title
            </h1>

            <p>Please upload your CSV file. The values containing addresses should be in a column named <em>address</em> or <em>Address</em></p>
            <form method='POST'>
                <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
                <button id="download">Submit</button>
            </form>
            <div class="results">
                <h3 class="base-pay">{{base_pay_Title}}</h3>
                <p class="base-pay-mean">{{ base_pay_MEAN }}</p>
                <p class="base-pay-high">{{base_pay_MAX}}</p>
                <p class="base-pay-low">{{base_pay_MIN}}</p>

                <h3 class="over-time">{{over_time_Title}}</h3>
                <p class="over-time-max">{{over_time_MAX}}</p>

                <h3 class="highest-paid">{{highest_paid_Title}}</h3>
                <p class="highest-paid-person">{{highest_paid_person}}</p>
                <p class="highest-paid-job">{{highest_paid_job}}</p>
                <p class="highest-paid-salary">{{highest_paid_salary}}</p>


                <h3 class="lowest-paid">{{lowest_pay_Title}}</h3>
                <p class="lowest-paid-person">{{lowest_paid_person}}</p>
                <p class="lowest-paid-job">{{lowest_paid_job}}</p>
                <p class="lowest-paid-salary">{{lowest_paid_salary}}</p>


            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is happening because Pandas is trying to read a local file instead of your submitted file.

Instead of reading the `form` dictionary, you need to access the `files` dictionary and pass its content to a Pandas DataFrame

```py
req = request.files.get('fileToUpload')
df = pandas.read_csv(req)
```

Comment: Now I'm getting this error:  ValueError

ValueError: Invalid file path or buffer object type: <class 'NoneType'>. Do I need to make any changes to my html file?

Comment: Executing the full example, i can notice that the file was not been uploaded to backend because the form is submitted as a form data not as binary data. At your HTML form you need to include the `enctype` to upload the file `<form method='POST' enctype="multipart/form-data">`